# Angular 2: Bind class just to selected element [ngClass]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, binding

I'm displaying arrows in a header table with icons from bootstrap, the problem is when i make click on a column all the columns get the icon class here is what talking about:
[image]

This is the code:

HTML ->

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <th (click)="orderBy('username')">Username<span [ngClass]="displayArrow()"></span></th>
    <th (click)="orderBy('email')">Email<span [ngClass]="displayArrow()"></span></th>
    <th (click)="orderBy('id')">Id<span [ngClass]="displayArrow()"></span></th>
    <th (click)="orderBy('roleId')">Role Id<span [ngClass]="displayArrow()"></span></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of usersListData | orderByController: OrderByParams">
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.username)">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.email)">{{user.email}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.id)">{{user.id}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.roleId)">{{user.roleId}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

AppComponent ->

```
private toggleArrow = 0;

orderBy(columnName: string) {
    this.toggleArrow++;
    if(this.toggleArrow > 2) {
        this.toggleArrow = 0;
    }
    console.log(this.toggleArrow);
}

displayArrow() {
    if(this.toggleArrow === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    else if(this.toggleArrow === 1) {
        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up';
    }
    else if(this.toggleArrow === 2) {
        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down';
    }
}
```

It's possible just bind the class to one element?

Comment: Yes possible. what do you want finally? show us that.

Comment: I want that the arrow show only in the clicked column not in all like in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant of solutions, but you can do something like this by declaring the columns in your component.

```
   columns: any[] = [
      {'Name':'username','Direction':0},
      {'Name':'email','Direction':0},
      {'Name':'id','Direction':0},
      {'Name':'roleId','Direction':0}
    ]
```

In your HTML you could do something like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="orderBy(col.Direction)">{{ col.Name }}<span [ngClass]="displayArrow(col.Direction)"></span></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of usersListData | orderByController: OrderByParams">
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.username)">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.email)">{{user.email}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.id)">{{user.id}}</td>
        <td (click)="onSelectFilterParam(user.roleId)">{{user.roleId}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

OrderBy would then be

```
orderBy(dir: number) {
    dir++;
    if(dir > 2) {
        dir = 0;
    }
    console.log(dir);
}
```

and finally the displayClass()

```
displayArrow(dir: number): string {
    if(dir === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    else if(dir === 1) {
        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up';
    }
    else if(dir === 2) {
        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down';
    }
}
```